# I want to get the count of roll number for each month

Tags: sql, oracle

| ID | STUDENT_ID | STATUS_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | 434120010026 | 25-FEB-22 |
| 1000 | 434120010026 | 03-MAY-03 |
| 1001 | 434120010026 | 25-FEB-22 |
| 1020 | 434120020023 | 18-MAR-22 |
| 1021 | 434120020025 | 18-MAR-22 |
| 1022 | 434120020025 | 16-MAR-22 |

Tried this

```sql
select count(*),
       trunc(status_date, 'mm')
from   test_studentattendance
group by trunc(status_date, 'mm');
```

got count of roll number in each month not the roll numbers.

| COUNT(*) | TRUNC(STATUS_DATE,'MM') |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-MAY-03 |
| 2 | 01-FEB-22 |
| 3 | 01-MAR-22 |

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: what do you mean by "roll numbers"?

Comment: I don't get it. In your title you say you want to get the count of roll numbers. You show a query that does this. And then you say that you get the count of roll numbers, not the roll numbers. Of couse, if you want to get the count of roll numbers and select the count of roll numbers, you get count of roll numbers. What the heck??? And besides, there doesn't even seem to be a role number in the table you are using. You are counting attendence rows, which is probably what you mean somehow, because you say "got count of roll number in each month".

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(*)` is counting the number of rows in each group and is counting students that appear in the same month multiple times.

To get the number on roll each month, you need to `COUNT` the `DISTINCT` identifier for each student (which, I assume would be `student_id`):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) AS number_of_students,
       TRUNC(status_date, 'mm') AS month
FROM   test_studentattendance
GROUP BY TRUNC(status_date, 'mm');
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_studentattendance (ID, STUDENT_ID, STATUS_DATE) AS
SELECT 1002, 434120010026, DATE '2022-02-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000, 434120010026, DATE '2003-05-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 434120010026, DATE '2022-02-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1020, 434120020023, DATE '2022-03-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1021, 434120020025, DATE '2022-03-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1022, 434120020025, DATE '2022-03-16' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS | MONTH |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 |
> | 1 | 2003-05-01 00:00:00 |
> | 2 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9aff245eced3bd2935465816bd97dbbb)*